# Create repository without using IQueryable for specification

Tags: c#, repository, iqueryable

I've recently been looking into DDD, repositories and the specification pattern and after reading a hand full of blogs and examples I'm trying to come up with a repository that I'm happy with.

I have been exposing IQueryable on my repositories until recently but after understanding that IQueryable is a leaky abstraction because of it is deferred execution and is effectively crossing the boundry from my data layer I have changed it so that my repositories return IEnumerable instead.

So I might have something like this for example:

```
public interface IUserRepository
{
    IEnumerable<User> All();

    void Save(User item);
    void Delete(User item);
}
```

I thought okay that seems good but what if I wanted to filter the data my firstname or email? After reading a blog post I implemented a way of passing ICriteria into the All() method.

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> All(ICriteria<TEntity> criteria)
{
    return criteria.BuildQueryFrom(Set).ToList();
    // Set is a DbSet from EntityFramework
}
```

And an example criteria class:

```
public class AccountById : ICriteria<Account>
{
    private readonly int _id;

    public AccountById(int id)
    {
        _id = id;
    }

    IQueryable<Account> ICriteria<Account>.BuildQueryFrom(DbSet<Account> dbSet)
    {
        return from entity in dbSet
               where entity.Id == _id
               select entity;
    }
}
```

This works fine and I can build these criteria classes to meet my requirements and pass them into the repos and all works well.

One thing I don't like though is being tied to IQueryable because I have to use an ORM that supports Linq so if I wanted to use SqlCommand in my repository for say performance sake or so I can write cleaner SQL rather than the ORM generated SQL, how would I go about doing that?

I would also like to avoid having to write a new method for each filter like FindById, FindByUsername, FindByEmail etc.

How would I go about creating a repository that allows me to specifiy the criteria I want to select without using IQueryable so it would still work whether I used EF, nHibernate or just plain SqlCommand? I'm stuggling to find an example that uses SqlCommand and the specification pattern.

How did people used to do it before ORMs?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I don't mind `IQueryable` being a leaky abstraction, because it allows me to write LINQ queries in my service layer and and therefore have more testable code. As long as objects that implement `IQueryable` are kept inside the service layer (i.e. don't return them to the presentation layer) I don't see a problem. It maximizes the testability of your application. See for instance [my blog post about testable LINQified repositories](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=84).

Comment: I do like IQueryable but I find if I write a service layer to turn IQueryable<T> into List<T> or IEnumerable<T> I find that I write a lot of "pass-through" methods where my service is just passing parameters and calling ToList() and nothing more and seems more work that its worth and that I might aswell just call the repository method itself.

Comment: When you're not doing more than returning more than simple CRUD operations, injecting your repository directly into the presentation layer could work, but in the applications I work on I see this hardly ever is the case. The queries get more complex. Don't forget that a criteria objects is in fact the same pattern as using `IQueryable` object. However, the language integration makes `IQueryable` much more pleasant.

Comment: This is true, I do actually use a service for my user operations like password encryprion and building a list of permissions etc, I was just hoping I could do away with IQueryable on my repositories so I could implement almost any if not any data access solution.